# Media query issue only exactly at 978px

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

I'll describe the issue first then show how my media queries are setup.

The issue is that at **exactly** 978px wide, media queries are being ignored.

Here's what my site looks like at [977px wide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbgrC.png)
And here's at [978px wide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hlzk.png)

The background image disappears. The background image is being set with media queries so that it can load smaller images on smaller devices.

Here's the code (SCSS):

```
//Desktop
@include desktop {
    background: $header-desktop-img;
}

//Tablet
@include tablet {
    background: $header-tablet-img;
}
```

And here are the media queries being used for desktop and tablet:

```
$break-desktop: 978px;    

//Desktop
@mixin desktop {
    @media (min-width: #{$break-desktop + 1}) {
       @content;
    }
}

//Tablet
@mixin tablet {
     @media ((max-width: #{$break-desktop}) {
          @content;
     }
}
```

As far as I understand, media queries are inclusive, so there shouldn't be a gap in the media queries, but for some reason there is.

If anyone has an idea how to fix this issue, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your browser is zoomed (as in 90%, 110%), this can cause rounding issues in certain cases which may be what you are experiencing. However, even if this is not the case, I would generally advise against using both min and max-width queries, and to instead go with a mobile-first approach. That is, to begin by writing the base styles to apply for the smallest possible screen, and then write only min-width queries that overwrite the previous breakpoints. In this approach, you are guaranteed not to have any gaps in your queries. For instance,

```
.some-selector {
    width: 100%;

    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
        text-align: center;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
        width: 50%;
        text-align: left;
    }
}
```